# Singleton going into an infinite loop

Tags: java, singleton

I'm using the singleton pattern to build a class, however it does receive another singleton as parameter, it isn't working, is that really possible?

This is the entire project: https://github.com/raphaelbgr/SwingSocketClient/tree/master/src

```
package clientmain;

import gui.janelas.JanelaMain;

public class ClientMain {

    public static int port              = 0;

    public static Thread receiver           = null;

    public static String ip                 = null;     
    public static String your_name      = null;     

    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        JanelaMain jam = JanelaMain.getInstance(); //JanelaMain extends JFrame
        jam.setLocationByPlatform(false);
    }
```

This is it's singleton block.

```
//SINGLETON PATTERN BLOCK
private static JanelaMain jam;
public static JanelaMain getInstance() {
    if (JanelaMain.jam == null) {
        jam = new JanelaMain(JanelaSelectServer.getInstance()); //Another one passed by parameter
    }
    return jam;
}
```

The other class Singleton block:

```
//SINGLETON PATTERN BLOCK
private JanelaSelectServer() {} //JanelaSelectServer extends another JFrame
private static JanelaSelectServer jsv;
public static JanelaSelectServer getInstance() {
    if (jsv == null) {
        jsv = new JanelaSelectServer();
    } 
    return jsv;
}
```

Shit happening (A Loop)

```
s.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.getInstance(JanelaMain.java:144)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.<init>(ConnectionLog.java:13)
at gui.updatelogs.ConnectionLog.getInstance(ConnectionLog.java:34)
at gui.janelas.JanelaMain.<init>(JanelaMain.java:37)
```

Thanks.

Comment: were you meaning to make `if (JanelaMain.jam == null) {` equal to `if (jam == null) {`

Comment: Wow, a Singleton depending on another Singleton? You may have invented a new anti-pattern there... I propose we call it *The Twingleton Pattern*, because twins also depend on each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not about those classes but about ConnectionLog class. You are trying to create an instance in JanelaMain and ConnectionLog tries to creates an instance of JanelaMain.

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class JanelaMain extends JFrame {

private FlowLayout layout                           = new FlowLayout();
private JTextField jtxt_send                        = null;

//CUSTOM SWING COMPONENTS
private ConnectionLog cn_log                = ConnectionLog.getInstance();
private TextLog msg_list                    = TextLog.getInstance();


@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ConnectionLog extends JTextField {

private JanelaMain jam = JanelaMain.getInstance();
```

Comment: You killed it, the loop is generated by the constructor calls, however, it wasn't supposed to consider that the static class value like null, and the loop should stop.

Answer (score 3):

Your code looks a bit strange, why giving a singelton to another? You can use the singelton class at the point where you need it and there is no need to give it to another class.